# X Server Crash in Fedora 9

Tags: fedora, x-server

I have a motif based application that runs on Fedora 9. This application has a functionality that calls itself periodically to perform a task using SIGALRM signal.

However the application seems to crash after a while.

Examining the logs, the X server seems to be crashing with the following logs:

****XIO:  fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server ":0.0"
      after 24275 requests (23960 known processed) with 0 events remaining***.*

Could someone please tell me what could be the problem?

Comment: Fedora 9 is very old, can you try running the same application on a newer version of Fedora?

Answer (score 1):

I have never had that problem, but searching the Internet yields [a similar problem](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=195131) which is finally traced down to a driver problem. Why are you still running Fedora 9? With a system that old you may not even be able to compile recent drivers for your video card ...

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to have nothing to do with the video card. The problem seems to be related to the way events may be processed by the X server.

Comment: You are correct I wouldn't rule out that the Xserver code has changed during the last 8 (!) release cycles ... maybe you want to upgrade?